# AVCaptureStillImageOutput and AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer image size discrepancy

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm facing an issue which is driving my crazy rightnow.

I have an app which has a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to show the camera, analog to snapchat.

When I take the still picture through AVCaptureStillImageOutput, it is way wider than the preview layer.

What I want to achieve is, that after taking the picture, the taken picture looks 1:1 same as in the preview, based on size.

```
    func takePicture(){
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo) {

        // make sure we have the proper device orientation set
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = previewLayer!.connection!.videoOrientation

        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) {
            (imageDataSampleBuffer, error) -> Void in
            // take the picture from output
            let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(imageDataSampleBuffer)
            let imageOriginal:UIImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!

            // imageOriginal must have the same aspect and size as the previewLayer!

        }
    }
}
```

I tried already with cropping based on calculated aspects, but this does not work.

The Previewlayer has the gravity allready set

```
previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
```

This doesn't change anything, and I think the fault lies within the stillImageOutput and not in the preview layer

If somebody knows help would be great, it looks like the whole AVFoundation-topic is very little covered across the www.

If somebody does not get what I mean, check those two screenshots from snapchat

[image: This is the preview layer of snapchat... sorry]

[image: This is after the take picture button was pressed... the picture has 1:1 the same size and bounds as the preview]